# using of NOT LIKE in MYSQL & getting error of SubQuery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have used below mysql query for fetching data:

```
select * 
from tableName 
where tableName.field_type='22' 
  and tableName.field_id NOT LIKE(select aField_id 
  from TableName 02 where status !='Active')
```

I am getting error

## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

can you let me know what wrong in this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from tableName
         where tableName.field_type='22' 
        and 
        tableName.field_id 
        NOT IN(select aField_id from TableName  where status !='Active')
```

Use `not in` in place of `not like`. `Not in` is for comparison of column with a set of values. `not like` is for comparison of column with a single value or pattern. Your subquery in returning more than one rows. `not like` can't handle that.

Comment: hello akshey,

thanks for your suggestion, i already try using NOT IN... but its returning 0 rows

Comment: Exactly what you want to achieve with the query?

Answer (score 1):

Like deals with only one input. So you  should use IN in place of LIKE.